# Specific child tag should not expand parent tag

Tags: css

I have HTML:

```html
<figure style="display:inline-block;">
   <img src="https://i.imgur.com/k1Crowy.jpg" width="200">
   <figcaption> This is some random text that should not expand the figure tag beyond the width of the img tag </figcaption>
</figure>
```

I want the `<figure>` tag to have the width of the `<img>` tag, which works just fine.

The problem is the content of the `<figcaption>` tag expands the width of the `<figure>` tag. How can I make it so the `<figcaption>` will be limited to the width of the `<img>` tag. So `200px` in above example.

I can't edit the HTML. Can only adjust CSS.

### What I've tried so far

1. `position:absolute` approach on `<figcation>`. Problem is that it won't expand the height of the `<figure>` tag.
2. Obviously, I can set a fixed width to `<figure>` tag (like `width:200px`), but I can't predict the width of the image.
3. jQuery approach where I grab the width of the image and add it to the `figure` tag. But I want to avoid a JS solution.

Comment: Beautiful. Every question should come with a *what i've tried so far* section. +1

Comment: do you want width of image size exactly?

Comment: @MohammedRabiullaRABI Yes.

Comment: `width:0;min-width:100%;` to figcaption

Comment: @TemaniAfif This looks like it is a hack, and may not work in all browsers.

Comment: there is no reason it doesn't work in all the browser since width/min-width are widely supported ... in case you find any bug with any browser you can edit your question to highlight it (as a side note, the question still remain a duplicate since the issue is the same, any new/better answer should be added to the dupliate target)

Comment: There is also [`width: min-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#min-content_2) (doing exactly that), but it's not widely supported.